# Correct implementation of fmap for Functors?

Tags: python, functional-programming, functor, applicative

So, I have been trying to wrap my mind around Functors, Applicatives and Monads lately. In my understanding such a design pattern allows one to separate "pure functions" from "impure" ones and ensure that there is no branching out and calling different functions from a given function and cause *side effects*.

So, let's say I have a dictionary and want to apply/compose some functions over it.

```
input = {"x": 2, "y": 5, "out": None}

def f(x):
    return x + 2

def g(y):
    return y - 3

def h(x, y):
    return x * y

class Functor:

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input

    def fmap(self, function):
        val = self.input
        if function.__name__ == "f":
            val["x"] = function(val["x"])
        elif function.__name__ == "g":
            val["y"] = function(val["y"])
        elif function.__name__ == "h":
            val["out"] = function(val["x"], val["y"])
        elif function.__name__ == "print":
            function(val)
        else:
            print("fmap not defined for this function!")
        return Functor(val)

    def __rshift__(self, function):
        return self.fmap(function)

Functor(input) >> f >> g >> h >> print #results in {"x": 4, "y": 2, "out": 8}
Functor(input) >> h >> g >> h >> print #results in {"x": 2, "y": 2, "out": 4}
Functor(input) >> g >> f >> h >> print #results in {"x": 4, "y": 2, "out": 8}
```

So, is my understanding of functors correct? If yes, is this the way one implements the *fmap*, or do you create a wrapper around each function so as to define the *fmap* inside the respective wrapper or what?
And, is this the way to keep track of the state of inputs, post function application?

Comment: A functor does not separate pure from impure functions but it allows you to lift pure functions into an computational context with a certain effect. Such an effect can be a computation that may fail, an asynchronous, non-deterministic or stateful computation. How do you apply a pure function to the result value of such an computation? With functor you don't need to answer this question anymore, because it abstracts from the application.

Comment: `fmap` can only be applied to components of a data structure of the same type. You can implement it for all elements of an homogenious array, but you can only implement it for the first or second field of a tuple. The same applies to your record type. What you've implemented is similar to a trifunctor except that you used meta programming, which is strictly forbidden in FP. A proper trifunctor would take 3 pure functions, one for each property and create a  new record containing the transformed properties.

Comment: @scriptum help me understand whether a functor is supposed to be for a limited number of functions and is not meant to carry the state around within it; or not. Because you said this is a tri-functor; I was thinking of chaining n-number of pure functions in such a way. If it is not so; could you show me how the above one is done in a correct manner?

Comment: @IvenMarquardt your first comment is actually an answer to the question.